# Cordova inAppBrowser unable to start download of pdf files displayed in opened html page in it

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am using cordova inappbrowser to open one html page using the function-

```
window.open(feedDetail, '_blank', 'location=yes'); //feedDetail holds the link to html
                                                    //page
```

The html page gets open very fine but when I am trying to click on a pdf link in the html page
it does nothing. Is inappbrowser incapable to download pdfs when using '_blank'. I don't want my page to open in system's browser using '_system' as that do not gives me the facility of going back to my app? Any suggestion what could be done in my case ?

Comment: Is this on Android? If so, I think you will need to download an app that allows opening PDF files because I'm pretty sure by default Android doesn't have a PDF viewer or anything.

Comment: yes,this is on Android and I have already installed Adobe reader do this task of opening the pdf files. If I am opening the page in system's browser, pdf starts downloading and then I am capable of opening it with Adobe reader but the problem is with inappbrowser when I am using _blank as the location. It displays the html page but when I am clicking on the  pdf link in it, it does nothing. Atleast it should start the download..rt?

Comment: For displaying a pdf in an app I had to use the cordova-plugin-document-viewer plugin.

Comment: Could you ever find a solution @Anilkumar ?